# How to split a character element to create a vector based on \n position

Tags: r

I have a character element like this...

```
element <- "\n\n\n\nPrivate trip\n\n\nPrivate trip \n\n\n\nFull Day Trip \n\n\n\n\n\nFREE Cancellation 3 days notice \n\n"
```

and I would like to split the element up to create a vector such that each vector element are the phrases in between the `\n`.  The desired result would be an element like this

```
result <- c("Private trip", "Private trip", "Full Day Trip", "FREE Cancellation 3 days notice")
```

I feel like the difficulty in this task lies in the fact that there aren't a constant amount of `\n` in between each phrase.  I have tried

```
strsplit(element, "\n", fixed = FALSE, perl = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE)
```

but this gives me a list with many empty elements.  I could work with this, but I feel like there might be a more efficient way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can specify one or more (`\n+`) along with zero or more spaces (`\\s*`)

```
out <- strsplit(element, "\\s*\n+\\s*")[[1]]
out[nzchar(out)]
#[1] "Private trip"                    "Private trip"                    "Full Day Trip"                  
#[4] "FREE Cancellation 3 days notice"
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `read.csv`

```
> trimws(unlist(read.csv(text = element, header = FALSE), use.names = FALSE))
[1] "Private trip"                    "Private trip"
[3] "Full Day Trip"                   "FREE Cancellation 3 days notice"
```

or `regmatches`

```
> trimws(unlist(regmatches(element, gregexpr("(\\w+\\s?)+", element))))
[1] "Private trip"                    "Private trip"
[3] "Full Day Trip"                   "FREE Cancellation 3 days notice"
```